# Solution to "this" reference changing inside callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of the issues I've been encountering again and again is the reference to the `this` pointer changing. Take the below example. I want to create a Server object, and store the resolution of the camera as a property. This is not possible, as `this.resolution` applies to a property in the camera callback object instead of the Server object.

```
function Server(options) {
    this.settings = options.settings;
    this.camera = options.camera;

    // Grab camera resolution
    this.camera.getImageResolution(function(err, data) {
        this.resolution = data;
    });
}

Server.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log(this.resolution); // This outputs an undefined variable error
}
```

In the past, I have worked around this by renaming `this` to `self` temporarily to call functions. This does not work when I am storing a value.  I would need to to pass `this` into the callback, which I obviously cannot do.

Additionally, I cannot use `apply`, as that would not allow `camera.getImageResolution` to call its own methods.

What is the best route to take in solving this issue? Please ask for clarification if my question is vague.

Comment: Why would you need to pass `this` into the callback? If you declare `self` in the outer scope, you can still reference it in the callback. You could also use `bind` to create a callback with a specific receiver.

Comment: @ethagnawl I would need to pass `this` into the callback because the above code is ran asynchronous. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: That's right, I can access `self` inside `getImageResolution`, but how would I put the values of `self` back into `this`?

Comment: @gluxon Ethagnawl is correct.  If you create a variable of var self = this; outside of your post, you'll be able to access it from inside the callback of your async operation.  And you don't need to reassign self to this.  Just use self at that point

Comment: @DavidL I posted a new comment seconds before you did, and ethagnawl just deleted his. Does my last comment change anything you said?

Comment: @gluxon  No, it would not.  The javascript this works differently than it does in C# or Java.  It will always naturally reassign itself to the appropriate context.  As such, just reference self as IF it were this, since for your particular needs in the callback, it is essentially this in the context of the outer scope.

Comment: @DavidL Post an answer with an example. I don't think I'm understanding what you're referring to. Note that `this = self` results in an error (just tried it).

Comment: @gluxon  Looks like ethangawl posted one :)

Comment: @DavidL That one doesn't solve the problem, or maybe I am horridly missing something.

Comment: @gluxon  I'm afraid I don't understand where this is going wrong for you.  Can you create a JSFiddle with a little bit more supporting code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Server(options) {
    var self = this;

    self.settings = options.settings;
    self.camera = options.camera;

    // Grab camera resolution
    this.camera.getImageResolution(function(err, data) {
        self.resolution = data;
    });
}

Server.prototype.start = function () {
    return this.resolution;
}

var server = new Server({options: {...}, settings: {...}});
server.camera.getImageResolution();
// after getImageResolution's asynch method has completed
server.start()  // === data parameter from getImageResolution's asynch method callback
```

Comment: Great, but how would I access `self.resolution` in another method?

Comment: `return this.resolution` gives undefined. `this` is never given the values applied to `self`.

Comment: There must be some other issue happening with your code. You'll see a contrived example based on my solution working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBfLt/1/

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new. `this` acts like a reference would in C++. The issue in my code was `getImageResolution` taking a second or two to complete, and I mistaked it for not copying the value over.

Comment: NP. Asynchronicity (not a real word?) can be tricky. Look into futures/promises if you find yourself fighting with nested callbacks, race conditions, etc.

Comment: As per Wikipedia, it's [*asynchrony*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony). I had that doubt too!